# Cakephp 2.4 + Static Page Rounting URL

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I really don’t like having /pages/ as part of the URL for my static pages.

If you had links pointing to www.example.com/pages/myPage/ they should now point to www.example.com/myPage.html

I have added **Router::connect(‘/(.*).html’, array(‘controller’ => ‘pages’, ‘action’ => ‘display’));**

Though i have added this in my Routes.php but its doesn't works for me.

Please help me if you know anything regarding this. 
Thanks in advance

---

Thanks, 
Hasmukh

Comment: You should define "doesn't work"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Router::connect('/my_page', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'my_page'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create the appearance of directories:

```
// app/View/Pages/about.ctp

Router::connect('/about',
    array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'about'));

// app/View/Pages/about/press-and-media.ctp

Router::connect('/about/press',
    array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'about/press'));

// app/View/Pages/about/press/press-releases.ctp

Router::connect('/about/press/press-releases',
    array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'about/press/press-releases'));

// app/View/Pages/about/contact-s.ctp

Router::connect('/about/contact-us',
    array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'about/contact-us'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your want:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
Router::connect('/:page.html', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'), array('pass' => array('page')));
```

And in a view you do this:

```
echo $this->Html->link(__('contact'), array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'page' => 'contact'));
```